# Plotting Longitude and latitude coordinates from WRF output

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a latitude  and longitude output in netcdf format for UK region from WRF (Weather research and forecasting model) runs. The latitude and longitude size is 147 rows and 117 columns. Now I am interested in plotting these using Matlab.
I am not sure if I am doing it the right way but this is my code.

```
clear all;
close all;

gridfile =strcat('path');
LON=ncread(gridfile,'LON'); LON = double(LON');
LAT=ncread(gridfile,'LAT'); LAT = double(LAT') ;

for i = 1:147
for j = 1:117

imagesc(LON(i,j)); hold on;
imagesc(LAT(i,j)); grid on ; 

end
end
```

It is not showing me the desired image. Please if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.
Thanks in advance
Shital

Comment: What's wrong with the image you're getting?

Comment: The image is a plot where x and y axis goes from 0.5 to 1.5. I dont know how and why  its plotting from 0.5 to 1.5. I want a plot where my horizontal axis (x) is all longitudes and vertical axis (y) is all latitudes, because this is the information contained in LON and LAT of my data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [axis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html)

Example, from -1 to 1 in `x` and -2 to 2 in `y`.

```
axis([-1 1 -2 2])
```

Comment: The actual lat / long should be trapezoids and not rectangular boxes.. how can i get that exact information from LAT and LON data plotted  ?